# Need USB drive to boot aspire one into Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, reboot, aspire-one

I just installed 12.04 LTS onto my Acer Aspire One from a USB thumbdrive, and I cannot reboot unless I boot from the USB drive. If I have the USB drive plugged in, it boots, and it looks like the system is running of the HDD (/ is mounted from there, the USB drive is /media/PENDRIVE, everything works fine when I unmount it, etc).

If I reboot with no USB drive mounted, I just get a flashing cursor. It looks like a misconfigured boot loader. The Terminal tells me that grub is not installed ... so just how does Ubuntu boot these days, and how can I make the HDD bootable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you have installed grub in the usb not in hard disk.

To install grub in hard disk,

1. Boot using ubuntu live usb,
2. install boot-repair by using the following commands.

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
3. Launch boot-repair from dash and perform a repair. If it doesn't fix remember the url notified by boot-repair tool (like `paste.ubuntu.com/`) and post the url.

A detail reading of boot-repair may help you, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: if you don't want to use some random ppa, you can just use this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/153083/199318