# My computer's not starting up without the Ubuntu usb

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

I installed  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my Dell Inspiron 1545 from a usb stick but it is not booting up when I removed the usb from the computer. but it is working when I put the usb in my computer. I want ubuntu to start without the usb. Please can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: check my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like grub has been installed to the usb.
From your booted Ubuntu system, open a terminal, then use the following commands to install grub to the internal drive  :

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

Replacing `sdX` with the actual drive, which will probably be `sda`, but use disk utility to double check if you are unsure.

[Accidently installed grub to usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153082/accidently-installed-grub-to-usb/153083#153083)

Comment: Boot-repair is a good resource. If you're not using EFI sometimes Ubuntu installs an EFI grub loader (grub-common) your computer might only support bios boot loading which is grub-pc.