# Desktop doesn't load after install/restart (dual boot)

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, mbr, gpt

I've just finished installing Ubuntu and Windows for dual boot on separate partitions. I installed Windows first because it's pickier about partition style (MBR) and that went fine. I shrank the disk and left a bunch of free space for Ubuntu.

I then installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop (in low graphics mode), but after finishing the install and getting to the prompt to restart the computer, it boots straight into windows without asking which operating system to load.

I suspect that the boot loader isn't being installed properly but I do not know how to verify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153481/my-computers-not-starting-up-without-the-ubuntu-usb/153487#153487). If you installed ubuntu using a USB, then grub may have been installed to the usb, try booting with the usb connected. If you then see grub and can boot ubuntu, follow our solution in the above link or look at [this page on my website](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/bootrepair.html) for more details.

If not you could try booting the live ubuntu disc and using [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: I used boot-repair but I think it did the same thing. It also replaced the grub-common loader (which is for EFI motherboards with grub-pc which uses the old bios) Which is important.

Comment: Please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair. It will give us valuable information to help you.