# I Installed Ubuntu many times, but it's not working, there is no option to boot Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, windows, wine

I installed Ubuntu in a Windows 7 PC in its `G:` partition. But after installation and restarting the PC, there is no option for boot to Ubuntu. I am not a computer expert. Please help me. During installation how do commands work.

Comment: after that i run ubuntu without installing to hdd, it works,

Comment: installed ubuntu , i like to keep windows, what will be sda

Comment: I suggest you to enter the askubuntu general chat room in order to receive real time advice from connected users, click here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 2):

Install it on your main drive, usually /dev/sda.

then use the command

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

It should automatically see your Windows partition, and you'll be rocking a dualboot.

Another option is to restore the Windows Bootloader after installing Ubuntu, and then proceeding to use EasyBCD to add a boot loader entry for Ubuntu.

I triple-boot OS X, Windows, and Ubuntu with the Chameleon Bootloader.

It automatically recognizes all my operating systems (all on separate drives within the same computer)!  Plus it has a GUI.  I love it!

Comment: It recognizes the Ubuntu partition as well??

Comment: If you're talking about Chameleon, in my case, I have ubuntu installed on a separate DISK.

Comment: EasyBCD does.  GRUB does too, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ubuntu using a USB, try booting the computer with the USB connected.
If you see Grub and Ubuntu boots then follow the [solution in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153481/my-computers-not-starting-up-without-the-ubuntu-usb/153487#153487).

EDIT : Extra info as requested

Hold  "ctrl & Alt" then press "T" and that will open a terminal.
Grub is the bootloader, basically a screen which will allow you to select booting Windows or Ubuntu (using the up / down arrows and pressing enter).

As suggested above try booting with the installation USB connected and let me know what happens.

`sdx` will probably be `sda` assuming you are installing to an internal hard drive and only have 1 internal drive. Linux uses sda, sdb, sdc to identify drives and sda1, sda2, etc to identify partitions on those drives. Windows uses letters like C, D, E etc to identify drives, partitions and devices which can make things complicated for new Linux users.

Comment: ok very good i can follow u. in my pc the hdd is 320 gb. installed windows7 installed in its C drive. and d and e are ntfs. f is cd drivei, g is pendrive. in my hdd 80gb free unallocated area. i like to install ubuntu with out disturbing existing windows7. what i hAVE TO DO?   CAN I USE SDA1

Comment: In that case, boot to a LiveCD or LiveUSB and select the "Something else" option and select the 80gb free space when prompted. You should read the answers from [install Ubuntu on a PC with 4 partitions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu/164161#164161), it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Windows and use EasyBCD to fix/adjust the boot setup.

[Here is the website](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) for EasyBCD.

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/140376/77449) on AskUbuntu. It describes how to setup EasyBCD for boot problems.

Edit: It could be a graphics driver problem, give [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139505/cant-access-ubuntu-12-04-black-screen-appears-when-trying-to-login) a read as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```