# Booting problem with Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: sudo, fbgrab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I Installed Ubuntu many times, but it's not working, there is no option to boot Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164775/i-installed-ubuntu-many-times-but-its-not-working-there-is-no-option-to-boot)

I would like to keep Windows..... What command should I use?
sudo grab_install /dev/_______________
plz help me