# No option to boot Ubuntu in a dual-boot system

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accidently installed grub to usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153082/accidently-installed-grub-to-usb)

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my VAIO laptop to use Windows 7 and Ubuntu at the same time. I chose the option said "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7".

After finishing the installation, my system was restarted and it boots and starts up with Windows. In other words, I do not have the Ubuntu option.

What should I do? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using a USB drive? If so, you have have accidentally put GRUB in the 
USB rather than the hard drive. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/153082/accidently-installed-grub-to-usb.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry, Ubuntu is still installed. You just need to access Windows boot manager by pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>. When the BIOS appears, then it will show you the operating systems loaded on Windows boot manager.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that GRUB never got installed properly.