# Install GRUB on USB afterwards

Tags: grub2, 18.04, live-usb

I managed to install GRUB to my local hard drive instead of my usb. So I have an ext4 stick with 128GB dedicated to Ubuntu, but I am only able to boot from the usb on a pc with already installed grub....

Can I Install Grub on the USB now afterwards? Does this work with boot-repair too? I hope this question isn't duplicate, as I saw similar questions like this:[Accidently installed grub to usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153082/accidently-installed-grub-to-usb) If this procedure applies to my problem too just let me know

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Is flash drive MBR or gpt? Your link should work but only if BIOS/MBR. If UEFI you have to have an ESP on gpt partitioned flash drive. If UEFI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix it like this with a second live usb:

1. Boot from the new ubuntu live usb
2. Install grub on the problem usb (according to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/153083/890260)

Now boot from the "not any longer" problem usb.
If you encounter a problem (after 90s not booting, emergency mode):

3. Boot in recovery mode, look which disk is shown as waiting task (dev-disk....*numbers*)
4. Boot again from the live usb and let the still problem usb in
5. Edit the /etc/fstab file from the problem usb by commenting out that disk shown in recovery mode as waiting ..... (commenting by "#" + "Space")

This worked for my problem at least..